# Selenium - driver.find_element_by_css_selector can't find the element (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I got a problem to use "find_element_by_css_selector" to get the element "Select" (a href).

I tried the methods below but all of them didn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.plan.right > a.select.").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='plan right']/div[2]/a/select").click()
```

Could anyone kindly give me some suggestions? Thanks!!

```
<div class="choose_plan">
   <h1>Sign up now for <strong>UNLIMITED</strong> access <br/>to all </h1>
   <div class="plans">
      <div class="plan left">
         <div class="head">
            <p>MONTHLY</p>
         </div>
         <div class="body">
            <p>annually</p>
         </div>
         <hr />
         <a href="/bbb?plan_id=6" class="select signup-dialog" data-planId="6" data-url="/users/new?r">SELECT</a>
      </div>
      <div class="plan right">
         <img alt="Popular-right" class="popular" src="/assetse8.png" />
         <div class="head">
            <p>14</p>
         </div>
         <div class="body">
            <p>Unlimited</p>
         </div>
         <hr />
         <a href="/account/purchase?plan_id=31" class="select signup-dialog" data-planId="31" data-url="/users/new?aaa">SELECT</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code. Is it the anchor tag (A) that you want selected?

Comment: Hi, e4c5, Ihave tried to format the code. Yes, I want to select "<a href="/bbb?plan_id=6" class="select signup-dialog" data-planId="6" data-url="/users/new?r">SELECT</a>" which under class "plan right".

Comment: How about find_element_by_link_text() ?

Comment: Because of I have another a href link under class "plan left", there are two "select", so, how do link_text() to figure out to click the one I want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to have well formed HTML, as line 15 (`<div class="choose_plan">`) appears to be unclosed. This solution below was done with this line removed, but the rest of the HTML as shown. You can test [online XPath here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='plan right']/a").click()
```

yields the following:

```
Element='<a href="/account/purchase?plan_id=31" class="select signup-dialog" data-planId="31" data-url="/users/new?aaa">SELECT</a>'
```

Comment: Hi Thane, driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='plan right']/a").click() is working! Thank you very much! And the link online XPath is very useful!

Comment: @betty Glad to help Betty. That link has saved me lots of time in figuring out XPath queries.

Comment: sorry may i know  this :   Element='<a href="/account/purchase?plan_id=31" class="select signup-dialog" data-planId="31" data-url="/users/new?aaa">SELECT</a>'  
Whether i need to insert this in my code?

Answer (score 5):

I know you already have an answer but there's a simple alternative that may be helpful in the future. From the HTML you provided, it looks like the `data-planId` attribute is unique for each `A` tag. You can take advantage of that using the code below.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-planId='31']")
```

See this [CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make it simple:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.right a.select")
```

Or:

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text("SELECT")[-1]
```

Here we are basically getting the last `a` element having `SELECT` text.

Comment: Hi alecxe, I tried the two methods and they didn't work after I tested. Since I got the answer from Thane, I'd like to thank you for spending time for my question.

Comment: @betty interesting. Still don't see why the other answer worked and the options here didn't. Anyway, glad to see the problem solved!